# How to check which cache features are turned on? [PHP/MYSQL]

Tags: mysql, caching, php

Is there an application or a code I can use to check which cache functions are turned on?

On this app I'm working on, I thought there was mysql cacheing, but since I started using the SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE in one of my queries (applied yesterday), the cacheing has not stopped. This leads me to assume it's a php cache function that's occurring.

I looked over php.ini for any possible cache features, but didn't see anything that stood out.

Which leads me to this:  Is there an app I can download or a Shell function I can input to tell me which cache functions are on or what may be causing the cache.

Comment: PHP doesn't have a built-in cache. Everything related to caching is wildly proprietary, so you will have a hard time finding an application that tells you which caching mechanisms are turned on. What exactly is your issue? What makes you think there is caching going on? You have cleared your browser cache?

Comment: There's a form that changes data values in the mysql database.  If you submit the form, then revisit the form, the newly inputted data is  not in the fields.  If I go away for a few hours and come back, the data is in the fields, but it goes into the database right after I hit submit.

Comment: I have mysql caches turned on - so maybe I'm just not working my mysql queries correctly with the sql_no_cache command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably already know that MySQL has a query caching mechanism. For instance if you have a table named users, and run a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`
```

It may take 3 seconds to run. However if you run the query *again*, it may only take 0.02 seconds to run. That's because MySQL has cached the results from the first query. However MySQL will clear it's cache if you update the users table in any way. Such as inserting new rows, updating a row, etc. So it's doubtful that MySQL is the problem here.

My hunch is your browser is caching the data. It's also possible that logic in your code is grabbing the old row, updating it, and then displaying the old row data in the form. I really can't say without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to close and restart your browser. I'd bet it is your browser caching not the back end.

Comment: No, This has been happening with everyone else working on the project - macs, pc, etc... - spreads across the spectrum

Comment: @Bob, if you aren't sending no cache headers, all browsers will behave the same. Have you tried updating, closing the browser, resetting the browser cache, then viewing the page again?